# fgets limiting input length

Tags: c

When I'm inputting data like a last name I have got it so it limits it to 10 characters, but when I try to enter the last name, the characters that were excluded from the first name are put into the last name. For example, if I enter `aaaaaaaaaab` it will keep the `a`'s but the `b` will be put into last name.

Any suggestions how I would fix this? I want it to limit the length to the correct amount.

```
printf("you chose add new record\n"); 
printf("enter the person information: \n");
printf("Please enter the first name: \n");
//limits to size 10
char namein[11];
fgets(namein, 11, stdin);
printf("the first name was: %s\n", namein);

printf("Please enter the last name: \n");
//limits to size 20
char lastin[21];
fgets(lastin, 21, stdin);
printf("the last name was: %s\n", lastin);
```

Comment: Do you want to insist that the first and last names are entered on two lines of input, or will you accept "firstname lastname" on a single line as valid?  The techniques to use are different.  The former is easier; you can read the whole line up front (with a _much_ bigger buffer) and use `sscanf()` to post-process the buffer.  Note that if someone enters `Jim E Cork`, your `fgets()` will get `Jim E Cork` into `namein`; it is not clear that's what you wanted. Also, the next `fgets()` would get just the newline after 'Jim E Cork', which is also not what you wanted.

Comment: i'm basically just going to be looking for the first 10 characters entered, so if the name was jimmyeguysZ the Z would be stripped off and save the input only as jimmyeguys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Examine the result of using `fgets()`.

If the buffer contains a `\n`, no need to look for more.  Otherwise consume potential extra data until `'\n'` or `EOF`.

```
int ConsumeExtra(const char *buf) {
  int found = 0;
  if (strchr(buf, '\n') == NULL) {
    int ch;
    // dispose of extra data
    while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
      found = 1;
    }
  }
  return found;
}

char namein[11];
if (fgets(namein, sizeof namein, stdin) == NULL) Handle_EOForIOError();
if (ConsumeExtra(namein)) Handle_ExtraFound();
```

Note: Recommend not being so small with input buffers.  Better to reads into a general large buffer and then qualify the input before saving to `namein`.  IOWs, prefer to keep input and scanning/parsing separate.

```
char buffer[100]
char namein[11];
if (fgets(namein, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) Handle_EOForIOError();
if (ConsumeExtra(buf)) Handle_InsaneLongInput();

int n = 0;
sscanf(buffer, "%10s %n", namein, &n);
if (n == 0 || buf[n]) Handle_NothingOrExtraFound();
```

Comment: okay thanks, but what exactly causes the extra letters being stripped off the first entering and added to the second?

Comment: @Austin Smith `ConsumeExtra()` consumes the extra `char` and tosses them in the [bit bucket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_bucket).  So when the next `fgets()` occurs, it retrieves fresh user input.

Answer (score -1):

You have to read the entire input buffer before doing the next read.  Such an operation is called "draining" the input.

So your code should look like

```
get the first name
read the first name
drain the input
print the prompt for the last name
read the last name
```

draining the input looks roughly like

```
while (there is data that can be read) {
  read a character
}
```

Comment: I think your 'draining' is a bit too enthusiastic; it should normally be 'while (the next character is not EOF or newline)`, if you are going to insist that the data is entered one word per line.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Perhaps, but really is anything before the presentation of the next query retainable?  I mean, if they hit carriage return five times, do you really want the next pulled input to be empty?

Comment: I guess it depends on what you mean by `while (there is data that can be read)`.  There isn't a standard function to look to see whether there are any more characters already in the input buffer.  Reading up to newline (or EOF if the last line doesn't have a newline) is a reasonable interpretation, but you might have some more complex scheme in mind.